# Debian. Сломалась боковая панель Nautilus

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

После того как завис ноутбук, перестал монтироваться раздел /home при запуске.
Починил с помощь fsck. Но, после этого при запуске nautilus в боковой панели появилась какая-то очень длинная строка, которая растягивает окно nautilus'а на несколько экранов.

[image: Скрин]

Отключение боковой панели помогает, конечно же, но как можно это починить?

Comment: А у вас нет возможности получить содержимое этой очень длинной строки?

Comment: По ней не работает не клик, не выделение, только при наведении появляется всплывающая подсказка с текстом: {"extension":

Comment: Именно без закрывающей фигурной скобки.

Comment: Правой кнопкой - удалить.

Comment: Правый клик тоже не работает по ней как и левый.

Comment: Всё, разобрался. Установив PCManFM смог таки глянуть, что это за строка. Просто чуть больше 30000 закладок)) Не понятно откуда взявшихся, но удалив их вернул себе нормальный nautilus.